# Matplotlib Scatter Plot over Geographical map, hiding background

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm attempting to plot a scatter-plot of a list of x and y values over a OpenMaps Map, the main issue is that when I generate the map, the scatter plot shows and the map doesnt, if I switch the order of the scatter and imshow the inverse is true, the map shows but not the scatter. I've tried fiddling with the aspect ratio and zorder no changes occur.

Pictures are below of the code and the output scatter not showing a map, any help would be much appreciated, I've tried a number of solutions from somewhat similar stackoverflow posts but so far none have worked, my suspicion is that the scatter is drawing itself over the top of the map with a white background.

```
def function(x):
y = []
z = []

#Create two lists of matching lat and long coordinates
for i in x:
    y.append(i[1])
    z.append(i[2])

#Turn off axis and axis ticks
plt.tick_params(labelbottom='off', labelleft='off', bottom='off', left='off')
plt.title("Bird Sightings")

#import map Image
img = mpimg.imread('map.png')

# MAP_EXTENT is (149.105, 149.130, -35.29, -35.27), variable set at top
plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=MAP_EXTENT)

plt.scatter(z, y, zorder=1)

#aspect=img.shape[0]/float(img.shape[1])*((MAP_EXTENT[1]-MAP_EXTENT[0])/(MAP_EXTENT[3]-MAP_EXTENT[2]))
#plt.gca().set_aspect(aspect)

#plt.savefig('pic.png', dpi=980)
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter No Map]

Comment: Please [do not post code as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), post it using the code markdown instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've revised it. My apologies. :)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please? The code looks fine (appart from indentation) to me.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use mplleaflet library. Very simple to use, you just need to provide the coordinates of the nodes in degrees. Take a look.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
from random import randint


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [randint(-10100, -9400)/100 for i in range(30)]
y = [randint(3700, 4000)/100 for i in range(30)]
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo')
mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the data that I was plotting was going far out of bounds of the restricted coordinates for the image so the image was not being shown at the scatter coordinates because it wasn't within those bounds.

Comment: Well done, happy for you. This prove the importance to share the dataset and the inputs though. Perhaps, we would be able to find it out sooner with the input. Next time ;)